# Run A Console Script From a Sublime Text 2 Keybinding

Tags: sublimetext2

I would like to run a single line console script to toggle spell_check in Sublime Text 2

```
view.settings().set('spell_check', True)
```

or

```
view.settings().set('spell_check', False)
```

via something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"], "command": "SOMETHING SIMILAR TO WHAT I HAVE ABOVE?" },
```

How do I enter this command into my keybindings file and how to I make it toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/settings.html
it looks like you should be able to do something like:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+s"],
    "command": "toggle_setting",
    "args":
    {
        "setting": "spell_check"
    }
}
```